# how to fix this participial sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

"Sitting in the shop, a car caught her eye. "

How to fix this to a right participial sentence? Not the car which is sitting in the shop, is the lady who is sitting in the shop.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is termed a *dangling modifier.* You could begin the sentence with "While she was sitting..."